# How do I override a var in a Kotlin class correctly?

Tags: android, class, kotlin, inheritance

I am trying to overwrite a value in a class. I have the following code:

```kotlin
open class Balloon() {
    open var textSize: Float = 20f
    init {
        Log.i("textSize", textSize.toString())
    }
}
    
class BigBalloon(): Balloon() {
    override var textSize = 30f
}
```

However, the Log prints out these values:

[image]

First Log is from `Balloon()`, second one is from `BigBalloon()`. How can it print `0.0` when I overwrote it as `30`? Did I implement all of this incorrectly?

Comment: I just checked your code and it prints `30.0` after creation of a `val bb = BigBalloon()` at `println(bb.textSize)`. The only difference is I had to remove the `init` block because I tried it in the Kotlin Playground which has no LogCat...

Comment: So that would mean the value is overridden correctly, but not inside init?

Comment: don't use non-final properties or functions in init blocks / constructors https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50222139/kotlin-calling-non-final-function-in-constructor-works

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Accessing abstract methods (in this case `getTextSize`) in constructor is generally discouraged since it might lead to artifacts like yours.

`BigBaloon` property override actually does two things:

1. creates new internal field - `BigBaloon.textSize`
2. overrides `textSize` getter and setter to access that field

It's a bit counter intuitive but it does NOT modify value of `Baloon.textSize` field, it's left untouched and inaccessible since getter/setter no longer use it.

Your issue is when `BigBaloon`s parent `Baloon` is being initialized it accesses `BigBaloon.textSize` which is NOT initialized at this point so it returns zero.

Answer (score 3):

Kotlin initialization order is not how you understand it, the init block of the Base (Balloon) class is called before the override is done. It is explained better in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49735604/kotlin-init-block-in-super-class-firing-with-null-properties-when-inheriting-fro). And here's the initialization order given in [Kotlin docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html#derived-class-initialization-order).

Put the property into primary constructor as:

```kotlin
Balloon(var textSize: Float = 20f) {
    // ...
}
```

And when you want to change it, just delegate it to the constructor:

```kotlin
class BigBalloon: Balloon(30f)
```